# What is the best way to create a form in asp.net mvc 5 for conditional inputs. Using the divs and render partial or Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a form in which I want the user to select using the radio button if its a company or individual user. Based on the selection I want to show and hide certain input fields like BirthDate, Gender etc (which is applicable for an individual user but not a company). I have tried different approach but each one has some or the other problem.

**Using Html.Partial in the View**

```
    <div class="companyDiv" style="display: none;">
        @Html.Partial("Company")
    </div>
    <div class="individualDiv">
        @Html.Partial("Individual")
    </div>
```

The radio button change event:

```
$("[name=IsIndividual]").on('change', function(){
                var $radio = $(this);

                var $individual = $radio.val();
                if ($individual == "True") {
                    $('.companyDiv').hide();                    
                   // $('.companyDiv').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('.individualDiv').show();                    
                  //  $('.individualDiv').prop('disabled', false);

                }
                else {
                    $('.individualDiv').hide();                   
                  //  $('.individualDiv').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('.companyDiv').show();                   
                 //   $('.companyDiv').prop('disabled', false);

                }
            });
```

Using this approach everything loads fine in the View but when I post it the fields which are present in both the partials become null in the controller. The reason to have the same fields in both partial is because I want to use same field in different way. Example - I have a firstName field which I use for first name in case of individual user but in case of company I want to use it to capture name with different labels and validations in both cases.

**Using Ajax approach**

Main Page

```
    $(function(){
        $("[name=IsIndividual]").on('change', function(){
            var $radio = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url:'@Url.Action("GetType", "Customers")',
                data: { IsIndividual: $radio.val() },
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data){
                    $("#loadpartial").html(data);
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetType(bool IsIndividual)
    {
        if (IsIndividual)
        {
            return PartialView("Individual");
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("Company");
        }
    }
```

Partial

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/select2")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/dataPicker")

    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                format: 'dd-M-yyyy',
                startView: 2,
                todayBtn: "linked",
                keyboardNavigation: false,
                forceParse: false,
                autoclose: true,
                showClose: true,
                showClear: true,
                toolbarPlacement: 'top'
            }
                ); 
});
    </script>

}
```

But in this case the controls like datepicker doesnt work. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here since I tried moving the script from main page to the partial.

Also since I am very new to this I am not sure what is the best practice to achieve this. Either of the 2 approach or something else altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using partial views, the issue is most likely that the element 'name' attributes are not being set with the correct prefix. Check the rendered html to see if the names being rendered from the partial are correct according to elements that are not part of the partial. If they don't match what the model binder expects then they will be null in the controller.

For the Ajax approach, the issue is that you are dynamically loading your elements so they are added to the DOM after the datepicker function has been called so it is not applied to them. You should call the datepicker function in the success function of your Ajax call rather than the document.ready function. The datepicker should then work.

And to actually answer your question, in this particular situation, I would recommend the ajax route as you will only be loading the content the user selects. But either approach is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did what you suggested for Ajax and it worked fine. But when I post my form and if it fails in controller because of Invalid model state then the loaded view doesnt have the partial. I understand that was loaded by Ajax but is there a way that in case of error on the server I can have my same view with data and errors retained?

Comment: You would need to return the view with the model from your action and have some logic based on the user's selection (which would need to be part of the model) that automatically loads the appropriate bit on document.ready, or as a partial.